# how to create overlay scaleable divs

Tags: jquery, html, css

i'm trying to create an image with overlay gradient image and text.
something like :

```
<div>
<img src="url"/>
 <div background-image="other url" background-repeat:repeat-x;>
  <h2>some text</h2>
 </div>
</div>
```

few notes:
* I need both images to scale correctly on width and height change.
* The  gradient img height is 96px and width 1 px.

what is the proper css for this kind of overlay? i have tried absolute/relative and define top in px but when resizing the gradient div change it's position and wasn't align to the bottom any more.
thanks   Gilad

CSS

```
.main{
    text-align:center;
}

.album {    
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.album-cover {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

.album-cover-gradient {
    height: 96px;
    background-image: url('../img/text-bg.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;

}
```

Comment: Your HTML is wrong.  `background-image="other url"` etc should be in the stylesheet and correctly syntaxed, or at least should be `style="background-image: url('')"`

Comment: it is in the css. i just want to show in a quick way that it is not an image but a div with background image.

Comment: Ok.  Maybe post the CSS in a separate code block to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you've used is incorrect (`background-image="other-url" background-repeat: repeat-x;`) should be `style="background-image: url('xxx')"; background-repeat: repeat-x;`.

However, that should really be put in an external stylesheet anyway.

Try something like this:

http://jsbin.com/Odiduce/1/edit

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding i have created with the style inside the html. of course the style is in a stylesheet file. your quick solution worked like a charm. i just needed to add max-width on the gradient div since it is 1 pixel width image. one more thing now it is align to left. how should i center it ?

Comment: You shouldn't need to add max-width to gradient div.  it will be 100% of it's container.  You say you want to align to left and to center it.  Can you clarify?

Comment: and yes - i have removed the max-width and it is ok...need to work these basics..

Comment: It's not aligned left though, because it's full width?  If the container has a defined width, then just use `margin: 0 auto;`